# Keep ssh tunnel open after running script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a device with intermittent connectivity that "calls home" to open a reverse tunnel to allow me to SSH into it. This works very reliably started by systemd and automatically restarted on any exit:

```
ssh -R 1234:localhost:22 -N tunnel-user@reliable.host
```

Now however I want to run a script on the `reliable-host` on connect. This is easy enough with a simple change to the `ssh ...` cli: swap `-N` for a script name on the remote `reliable-host`:

```
ssh -R 1234:localhost:22 tunnel-user@reliable.host ./on-connect.sh
```

The problem is that once the script exits, it closes the tunnels if they're not in use.

One workaround I've found is to put a long `sleep` at the end of my script. This however leaves `sleep` processes around after the connection drops since `sleep` doesn't respond to `SIGHUP`. I could put a shorter sleep in an infinite loop (I think) but that feels hacky.

**`~/on-connect.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do stuff...

sleep infinity
```

How can I get `ssh` to behave like `-N` has been used so that it stays connected with no activity but also runs a script on initial connection? Ideally without needing to have a special `sleep` (or equivalent) in the remote script but, if not possible, proper cleanup on the `reliable-host` when the connection drops.

Comment: The issues with the sleep may be solved by doing sleep on the client side: `(echo ./on-connect.sh ; while sleep 10 ; do echo "" ; done ) | ssh ...`. The loop should terminate when ssh will terminate

Comment: @dash-o Not a bad idea. I'll try it.

Comment: @oguzismail `.bashrc` is not sourced when `-N` is used.